# Can we change the text align without moving the position of an object in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, alignment

Is there such an option we can turn on so when we change the text align of an text object the position of this object will not move in Illustrator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can realign the point text with the original. This could be useful if you ever used point text an need a second line below aligned. Do this:

1. select your text.
2. hit copy.
3. realign your text (yes it moves).
4. paste in front.
5. align the realigned text with the align tool.
6. delete the old copy.

[image]

**Animation 1:** This is what the described sequence gets you.

Answer (score 4):

When we change the text align of an text object of "Point Type" the position of this object will move. In order to avoid this behavior, we have to change the type of the text block to "Area type". Go to "Type" menu and select "Convert to Area Type".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! As it is a one-time thing. 
You could also create a custom shortcut (Ctrl + Shift + T) to toggle the type conversions while changing the text alignment.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, changing the alignment means move it to align somewhere different.

You can use Area text rather than point text, However, altering alignment will still move text. Left align text will never automatically fall in the same position if you change it to right aligned.

Comment: i think there is a usecase for this kind of stuff. If you only originaly had one line of text and later need text under it right aligned could be a usecase. You could do this by copying the text, changing alignment (and thus let it move), paste in front and align the items then delete the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier solution to this problem... Hope this helps some... I had a menu, that got created back to Illustrator from a PDF... once it does this typically it loses some if not all of the text formatting  and some text may even convert to outline - but that's another problem ;)  So In this example I needed to do some simple price changes... the prices if I changed them of course were left aligned and then would be time-consuming it would be to temp them, align them, move them etc.. this saves lots of time...

Another poster was half right... take your text (assuming its point text), click it
[image: Step 1]

Select the text and then click the round dot to the right of the text, this converts to Area type. It may move slightly but no worry...
[image]

Next Step change the Paragraph type to the alignment you wanted
[image]

And finally, click to change it back to point text
[image]

The text will be same exact location, just the alignment of the paragraph has changed.
[image]

For a solution to simply move to center little quicker, use the AlignTextFieldCenter script found here http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no tab or other invisible character after the text, it will change it's behavior when selecting paragraph options, left justify, center or right justify. With a tab after a piece of text it moves the whole text box with no tab, it moves the text inside the box.